# Proving that a sequence is exact and non-split

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Here is the sequence that I want to show that it is exact and non-split:

Let $K = (a)$, $O(a) = 2$ like $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and Let $L = (b)$, $o(b) = 4$  like $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.$ Consider the following exact sequence of abelian groups ($\mathbb{Z}$-modules)   $$0 \to K \xrightarrow{i} L \xrightarrow{p} K \to 0 $$ where the map $i$ is defined by $a \mapsto 2b$ and the map $p$ is defined by $p(b) = a$.

**My try:**

Showing that it is exact:

I know that I should show that $i$ is injection, $p$ is onto and $\ker(p) = \operatorname{Im}(i).$ First $i$ is injection because it is the inclusion map. Second $p$ is onto because it is the projection map. Third. To show that $\ker(p) = \operatorname{Im}(i)$, I will calculate $\ker(p)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(i)$. Since $\ker(p) = \{b \in L \mid p(b) = 0\} =  \{b \in L \mid a = 0\}$ and since $\operatorname{Im}(i) = \{i(a) \mid a \in K \}$, then I do not know how to conclude that they are equal.

For the non-split part:

I do not know exactly how should I prove it. The splitting criteria I know is:

> Let $0 \to  M' \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} M'' \to 0$ be an exact sequence of $A$-modules. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists $\psi \colon M \to M'$ with $\psi \circ f = 1_{M'}$.
> 2. $M = \ker(g) \oplus \ker(\psi)$.
> 3. There exists $\phi \colon M'' \to M$ with $g \circ \phi = 1_{M''}$.
> 4. $M = \operatorname{Im}(f) \oplus \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$.

But I can not conclude/guess which condition will not be fulfilled in our sequence. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $K=\{0,a\}$, and that $L=\{0,b,2b,3b\}$.
Hence, all the values of $i$ and $p$ are
$$
i(0)=0, \quad i(a)=2b, \\
p(0)=0, \quad p(b)=a, \quad p(2b)=2a=0, \quad p(3b)=3a=a.
$$
Thus,
$$
\ker i = \{x \in K : i(x)=0\} = \{0\}, \\
\operatorname{im} i = \{i(x) : x \in K\} = \{0,2b\}, \\
\ker p = \{y \in L : p(y)=0\} = \{0,2b\}, \\
\operatorname{im} p = \{p(y) : y \in L\} = \{0,a\} = K.
$$
That is, the sequence is exact.

Finally, if there were a map $r \colon L \to K$ such that $r \circ i = 1_K$, then
$$
a=r(i(a)) = r(2b)=2r(b) = 0,
$$
(in $K$, every element $x$ satisfy that $2x=0$) which is absurd.

Hence, the sequence doesn’t split.

Answer (score 3):

All three are not fulfilled.   For instance,  $\Bbb Z_4\not \cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.

So the sequence is not split.

---

For exactness,  you have $p\circ i(x)=p(2x)=0\in\Bbb Z_2$.  And so $\rm{im}(i)\subset \rm{ker}(p)$.

But both sets have order $2$ (by the first isomorphism theorem, since $\Bbb Z_4/\rm{ker}(p)\cong\Bbb Z_2$), so they are equal.

Comment: What about my other questions? I want to show that  it is non split not just say an example ..... I also forgot to write the fourth criteria ..... I will write it now.

Comment: But in your question $M=\Bbb Z_4$ and $M'=M''=\Bbb Z_2$.  I thought you showed it was exact.

Comment: Hold on, I read the first part too fast.

Comment: I am saying that K **like** the group $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z$ not it is it.

Comment: But there's only one group of order two.  This won't be true for just any groups.

Comment: In  your last line can you clarify the details of showing that both sets have order $2$ please?

Comment: See my edit, please.