# Proving that another sequence is exact and non-split (Correcting the function $p$ to make it exact)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

In connection to my previous question here  [Proving that a sequence is exact and non-split](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603487/proving-that-a-sequence-is-exact-and-non-split) I want to solve the question below:

Let $K = (a)$, $O(a) = 2$ like $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and Let $L = (b)$, $o(b) = 4$  like $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.$

Let $N$ be any $\mathbb Z$-module. Show that the sequence $$0 \to K \xrightarrow{i} L \oplus N \xrightarrow{p} K \oplus N \to 0 $$ with the maps $i$ defined by $a \mapsto (2b, 0)$ and $p$  defined by $(b, n) = (p(b), n)$ is exact and non-split.

**My thoughts**

**I believe it is not exact as I have that $\operatorname{ker}(p) = \{(0,0)\}$ while $\operatorname{Im}(i) = \{(0,0), (2b, 0)\}.$ am I correct?**

**And then, according to the following criteria it is non-split because it is not exact. right?**

The splitting criteria I know is:

> Let $0 \to  M' \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} M'' \to 0$ be an exact sequence of $A$-modules. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists $\psi \colon M \to M'$ with $\psi \circ f = 1_{M'}$.
> 2. $M = \ker(g) \oplus \ker(\psi)$.
> 3. There exists $\phi \colon M'' \to M$ with $g \circ \phi = 1_{M''}$.
> 4. $M = \operatorname{Im}(f) \oplus \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$.

**Now, to correct it to be exact, I believe we should change the definition of $p$ to  $(b, n) = (p(b), n),$ right?**

But then, for non-splitting, I applied the same idea of the referred question above but with the following modifications:

if there were a map $r \colon L \oplus N \to K$ such that $r \circ i = 1_K$, then
$$
a=r(i(a)) = r((2b,0))=2r((b,0)) = 0,
$$
(in $K$, every element $x$ satisfy that $2x=0$) which is absurd. Hence, the given sequence is non-split.\

**am I correct?**

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Okay, $p$ is defined by $(b,n) \mapsto (p(b),n)$… but what is $p(b)$? Is it $a$ (like in your previous question)?

Comment: @azif00 yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $p$ is defined by
$$\forall n \in N, \quad 
p((x,n)) = \begin{cases}
(0,n) & \textrm{if } x=0 \\
(a,n) & \textrm{if } x=b \\
(0,n) & \textrm{if } x=2b \\
(a,n) & \textrm{if } x=3b \\
\end{cases}
$$
the sequence **is exact**: Since $p((2b,0))=(0,0)$, we have that $\ker p$ contains $\{(0,0),(2b,0)\}$.
On the other hand, if $(x,n) \in \ker p$, the equality $p((x,n)) = (0,0)$ implies that $x$ is equal to $0$ or $2b$ and that $n=0$.
Hence $\ker p = \{(0,0),(2b,0)\} = \operatorname{im} i$.

The argument of that doesn’t exists a map $r \colon L \oplus N \to K$ such that $r \circ i = 1_K$ is correct.
Hence, the sequence is exact and non-split.

Comment: Ok, so we are taking $n=0$?

Comment: @Brain In your previous question, the value of $p$ at $b$ determined all the other values (since, assuming that $p$ is a homomorphism, $p(kb) = kp(b)$ for $k=0,1,2,3$).
In this case, the value of $p$ at $(b,n)$, with $n \in N$, *does not* determine all the other values.
We must assume that $p$ "behaves" as a homomorphism in the first coordinate and as the identity in the second.
I explicitly write what we mean by this at the beginning of my (just edited) answer. Hope this clarify the things :)